# How to render/draw buffer object to framebuffer without glDrawPixels

Tags: opengl

According to opengl spec 4.0 glDrawPixels is deprecated.

For cuda interoperability it seems best to use "opengl buffer objects". (An alternative could be textures or surfaces but these have caching/concurrency issues and are therefore unusable for my cuda kernel).

I simply want to create a cuda kernel which uses this mapped opengl buffer object and uses it as a "pixel array" or a piece of memory holding pixels, later the buffer is unmapped.

I then want the opengl program to draw the buffer object to the framebuffer. I would like to use an opengl api which is not deprecated.

What other ways/apis are there to draw a buffer object to the frame buffer ? (Also render buffers cannot be used since they probably have same issue as cuda arrays/caching issues, so this rules out framebuffer object/extension ?!?).

Is there a gap/missing functionality in opengl 4.0 now that glDrawPixels is deprecated ? Or is there an alternative ?

Comment: I don't understand. Your first point states that OpenGL Buffer Objects are recommended for CUDA/OpenCL-OpenGL interop (and they are). Are you looking for other alternatives or is there some issue with that avenue?

Answer (score 6):

`glDrawPixels` has been *removed* from GL 3.2 and above (it is not deprecated. Deprecated means "available but to be removed in the future"). It was removed because it's generally not a fast way to draw pixel data to the screen.

Your best bet is to use [`glTexSubImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexSubImage2D) to [upload it to a texture](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object), then draw that to the screen. Or blit it from the texture with [`glBlitFramebuffer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBlitFramebuffer).

Comment: @SkybuckFlying: The glBlitFramebuffer part was an alternative to the drawing it to the screen. That is, you attach the texture that you uploaded the pixel data to an FBO, then *blit* it to the screen. You're going to be using glTexSubImage2D regardless; it's just a question of whether you're drawing a textured quad or blitting from the texture to the default framebuffer.

Comment: @SkybuckFlying: That's not Wikipedia; that's the OpenGL Wiki. And what exactly isn't it clear on?

Comment: @SkybuckFlying use `glBindFramebuffer` with `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`/`GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`, but I agree finding this isn't trivial. It really does seem that `glDrawPixles` is *far* more direct. Is it actually slower?