# Sorting Pixels from opengl using CUDA and Thrust (Windows Port Issues...)

Tags: opengl, cuda, thrust

I tried to port [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966586/sorting-pixels-from-opengl-using-cuda-and-thrust) to WINDOWS with GLFW, since I don't have access to Linux box .. but the only thing I get is the clear color and nothing comes up ..

Did others get this example to work / Did I miss something here?

I do not even get the original image, before the sort either ...

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h> 


const int WIDTH=800;  
const int HEIGHT=800;
const int DIM = 800;

GLuint  bufferObj;
cudaGraphicsResource *resource;



struct sort_functor
{
    __host__ __device__
        bool operator()(uchar4 left, uchar4 right) const
    {
        return (left.y < right.y);
    }
};



// create a green/black pattern
__global__ void kernel(uchar4 *ptr) {
    // map from threadIdx/BlockIdx to pixel position 
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    // now calculate the value at that position 
    float fx = x / (float)DIM - 0.5f;
    float fy = y / (float)DIM - 0.5f;
    unsigned char   green = 128 + 127 * sin(abs(fx * 100) - abs(fy * 100));

    // accessing uchar4 vs unsigned char* 
    ptr[offset].x = 0;
    ptr[offset].y = green;
    ptr[offset].z = 0;
    ptr[offset].w = 255;
}


static void sort_pixels(){
    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &resource, NULL);
    uchar4* devPtr;
    size_t  size;

    cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void**)&devPtr, &size, resource);

    thrust::device_ptr<uchar4> tptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(devPtr);
    thrust::sort(tptr, tptr + (DIM*DIM), sort_functor());
    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &resource, NULL);

}


void GLFWCALL Keyboard_Callback(int key, int action)
{
    if (key == 32 && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        sort_pixels();

    return;
}



int main ()
{

    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    if( !glfwOpenWindow( WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetWindowTitle( "Sort Test" );
    glfwEnable( GLFW_STICKY_KEYS );

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glClearColor(0.087, 0.087, 0.087, 1.0);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(Keyboard_Callback);



    // SORT CODE
    glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObj);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, bufferObj);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, DIM * DIM * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&resource, bufferObj, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone);

    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &resource, NULL);
    uchar4* devPtr;
    size_t  size;
    cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void**)&devPtr, &size, resource);

    dim3    grid(DIM / 16, DIM / 16);
    dim3    threads(16, 16);

    kernel << <grid, threads >> >(devPtr);

    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &resource, NULL);



    do{ 
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable (GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        glDrawPixels(DIM, DIM, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

        glfwSwapBuffers();


    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
           glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED ) );

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;

}
```

Edit:

I added :

```
static void HandleError(cudaError_t err, int line) {
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), "main", line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::cout << "What happened : " << line << " " << cudaGetErrorString(err)<< std::endl;
}
#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))
```

with and example call:

```
HandleError(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&resource, bufferObj, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone), 134);
```

Per the comments, no CUDA errors?
so does that mean there is something wrong with the binding of the PBO or draw commands?

Comment: I would start by adding [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) to all of the CUDA API calls and kernel calls.

Comment: Followed your advice :
no error were returned ... :(
So is the binding then?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version of the program that seems to work for me under windows.

Rather than going through the details of project setup, just drop this code in the [simpleGL](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-opengl) cuda sample code, in place of the code that is there,  and rebuild that project.

windows version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// OpenGL Graphics includes
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>


static void HandleError( cudaError_t err, const char *file,  int line ) {
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
            printf( "%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString( err ),  file, line );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))

#define     DIM    512

GLuint  bufferObj;
cudaGraphicsResource *resource;

struct sort_functor
{
  __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(uchar4 left, uchar4 right) const
    {
      return (left.y < right.y);
    }
};



// create a green/black pattern
__global__ void kernel( uchar4 *ptr ) {
// map from threadIdx/BlockIdx to pixel position
  int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
  int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

// now calculate the value at that position
  float fx = x/(float)DIM - 0.5f;
  float fy = y/(float)DIM - 0.5f;
  unsigned char   green = 128 + 127 * sin( abs(fx*100) - abs(fy*100) );

// accessing uchar4 vs unsigned char*
  ptr[offset].x = 0;
  ptr[offset].y = green;
  ptr[offset].z = 0;
  ptr[offset].w = 255;
}

static void draw_func( void ) {

  glDrawPixels( DIM, DIM, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );
  glutSwapBuffers();
}
static void sort_pixels(){
  cudaGraphicsMapResources( 1, &resource, NULL );
  uchar4* devPtr;
  size_t  size;

  cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer( (void**)&devPtr, &size, resource);

  thrust::device_ptr<uchar4> tptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(devPtr);
  thrust::sort(tptr, tptr+(DIM*DIM), sort_functor());
  cudaGraphicsUnmapResources( 1, &resource, NULL );
  draw_func();
}

static void key_func( unsigned char key, int x, int y ) {
  switch (key) {
    case 27:
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource( resource ) );
        glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0 );
        glDeleteBuffers( 1, &bufferObj );
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 32:
        sort_pixels();
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  cudaGLSetGLDevice( 0 );

  glutInit( &argc, argv );
  glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA );
  glutInitWindowSize( DIM, DIM );
  glutCreateWindow( "sort test" );
  glewInit();
  glGenBuffers( 1, &bufferObj );
  glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, bufferObj );
  glBufferData( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, DIM * DIM * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB );

  cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer( &resource, bufferObj, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone );


  cudaGraphicsMapResources( 1, &resource, NULL );
  uchar4* devPtr;
  size_t  size;

  cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer( (void**)&devPtr, &size, resource);
  dim3    grid(DIM/16,DIM/16);
  dim3    threads(16,16);
  kernel<<<grid,threads>>>( devPtr );
  cudaGraphicsUnmapResources( 1, &resource, NULL );

// set up GLUT and kick off main loop
  glutKeyboardFunc( key_func );
  glutDisplayFunc( draw_func );
  glutMainLoop();
}
```

The previous linux version probably has some cruft in it.  It wasn't intended to be a paragon of programming, just something to demonstrate the concept, so I picked up a previous example I had laying around.  This version is probably a little bit "cleaner".

Also note that the above code works as-is (for me, anyway) on linux if I compile with:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o ogltest3 ogltest3.cu -lglut -lGLEW
```

Here's an updated version, that works on windows or linux, and does not use `glDrawPixels`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// OpenGL Graphics includes
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>


static void HandleError( cudaError_t err, const char *file,  int line ) {
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
            printf( "%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString( err ),  file, line );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))

#define     DIM    512

GLuint  bufferObj;
GLuint  textureID;
cudaGraphicsResource *resource;

struct sort_functor
{
  __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(uchar4 left, uchar4 right) const
    {
      return (left.y < right.y);
    }
};



// create a green/black pattern
__global__ void kernel( uchar4 *ptr ) {
// map from threadIdx/BlockIdx to pixel position
  int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
  int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

// now calculate the value at that position
  float fx = x/(float)DIM - 0.5f;
  float fy = y/(float)DIM - 0.5f;
  unsigned char   green = 128 + 127 * sin( abs(fx*100) - abs(fy*100) );

// accessing uchar4 vs unsigned char*
  ptr[offset].x = 0;
  ptr[offset].y = green;
  ptr[offset].z = 0;
  ptr[offset].w = 255;
}

static void draw_func( void ) {

//  glDrawPixels( DIM, DIM, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );

  glutSwapBuffers();
}
static void sort_pixels(){
  cudaGraphicsMapResources( 1, &resource, NULL );
  uchar4* devPtr;
  size_t  size;

  cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer( (void**)&devPtr, &size, resource);

  thrust::device_ptr<uchar4> tptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(devPtr);
  thrust::sort(tptr, tptr+(DIM*DIM), sort_functor());
  cudaGraphicsUnmapResources( 1, &resource, NULL );
  glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, bufferObj);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
  glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, DIM, DIM, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2f( 0, 1.0f);
  glVertex3f(-1.0,1.0f,0);
  glTexCoord2f(0,0);
  glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,0);
  glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0);
  glVertex3f(1.0f,-1.0f,0);
  glTexCoord2f(1.0f,1.0f);
  glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f,0);
  glEnd();

  draw_func();
}

static void close_func( void ){
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource( resource ) );
        glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0 );
        glDeleteBuffers( 1, &bufferObj );
        exit(0);
}

static void key_func( unsigned char key, int x, int y ) {
  switch (key) {
    case 27:
        close_func();
        break;
    case 32:
        sort_pixels();
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  cudaGLSetGLDevice( 0 );

  glutInit( &argc, argv );
  glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA );
  glutInitWindowSize( DIM, DIM );
  glutCreateWindow( "sort test" );
  glewInit();
  glGenBuffers( 1, &bufferObj );
  glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, bufferObj );
  glBufferData( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, DIM * DIM * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB );

  cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer( &resource, bufferObj, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone );
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
  glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, DIM, DIM, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


  cudaGraphicsMapResources( 1, &resource, NULL );
  uchar4* devPtr;
  size_t  size;

  cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer( (void**)&devPtr, &size, resource);
  dim3    grid(DIM/16,DIM/16);
  dim3    threads(16,16);
  kernel<<<grid,threads>>>( devPtr );
  cudaGraphicsUnmapResources( 1, &resource, NULL );

  glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, bufferObj);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
  glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, DIM, DIM, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2f( 0, 1.0f);
  glVertex3f(-1.0,1.0f,0);
  glTexCoord2f(0,0);
  glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,0);
  glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0);
  glVertex3f(1.0f,-1.0f,0);
  glTexCoord2f(1.0f,1.0f);
  glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f,0);
  glEnd();
  draw_func();

// set up GLUT and kick off main loop
  glutCloseFunc( close_func );
  glutKeyboardFunc( key_func );
  glutDisplayFunc( draw_func );
  glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Is glDrawPixels depreciated? I just read so is that giving me an issue on windows .. such I have to map it to a texture?

Comment: It may be either deprecated or removed depending on OGL version.  The code above works for me, if you follow the recommendation I made to drop it into the simpleGL sample project and rebuild that project.  Anyway, converting from glDrawPixels to some other rendering approach is [an OpenGL topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164276/how-to-render-draw-buffer-object-to-framebuffer-without-gldrawpixels), right?  I don't think it depends on CUDA in any way.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add an additional version of the code that does not use `glDrawPixels`, using a texture instead.