# Alternative ways to draw pixels or lines on screen

Tags: c, opengl, sdl, glew

I define my SDL2 window as follows:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);        // red: 8 bits
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);      // green: 8 bits
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);       // blue: 8 bits
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);      // alpha: 8 bits
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);    // r + g + b + a = 32 bits
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
graphWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
```

Then, with the following struct, I create an array of pixels and use that array as the buffer that is passed to SDL:

```
typedef struct {
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
    float a;
} Pixel;

// ...

void main(void) {
    Pixel *pixels;
    // ...
    pixels = malloc(width * height * sizeof(Pixel));
    // ...

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    while (graphNotClosed) {
        glDrawPixels(width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
        // do some number cruching and change some elements of array "pixels"
        // ...
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(graphWindow);
    }
}
```

The thing that bothers me is, though the code sometimes change *one and only one pixel* in the `while` loop, I still keep passing the *whole* array (with `width * height`) to the SDL (via `glDrawPixels`) in each iteration.

And my question: Is this a must (and only way) to pass the whole array to SDL or is it possible to inform the SDL just the pixel(s) that had been altered from the previous state, in the name of accelerating the graphics process.

Comment: If you want just pixel-based drawing, why bother with OpenGL which is best at 3d-drawing? There are many good 2d libraries which can help you, even ones using SDL for the lower layers (which OpenGL doesn't do).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Unfortunately, my "C graphics" google search mostly came with OpenGL results. That's why I used OpenGL. I'll be pleased to hear alternative suggestions for **2D** drawing in C (just lines, pixels, etc)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render/draw buffer object to framebuffer without glDrawPixels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164276/how-to-render-draw-buffer-object-to-framebuffer-without-gldrawpixels)